# PHP70-FPM ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, php-fpm, php7

I am continuously receiving following errors in my `php-fpm` logs. I have read and tried some similar question available on serverfault.com but Issue does not resolved.

```
[11-Apr-2017 08:33:27] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 09:49:26] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 09:49:26] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 09:56:11] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 09:56:11] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:09:56] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:09:56] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:22:39] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:22:39] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:35:52] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:35:52] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:38:52] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:46:33] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:46:33] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:54:21] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:54:21] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 10:59:17] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:03:16] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:03:16] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:05:50] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:05:50] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:05:50] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:05:50] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:12:03] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:32:45] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:32:45] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:48:28] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:48:28] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:53:11] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:55:15] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 11:55:15] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 12:06:17] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
[11-Apr-2017 12:06:17] ERROR: unable to read what child say: Bad file descriptor (9)
```

My OS is CentOS7 and I am using `PHP7-FPM` with `nginx`

Server specification are below

Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1620v2

Sever Ram: 64GB DDR3

My current fpm configurations are below

```
pid = /run/plesk-php70-fpm.pid

error_log = /var/log/plesk-php70-fpm/error.log

log_level = error

emergency_restart_threshold = 10
emergency_restart_interval = 1m
process_control_timeout = 10s

listen.backlog = 65535

;[php-fpm-pool-settings]
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 2000
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
#pm.max_requests = 10000

#pm = dynamic
#pm.max_children = 5000
#pm.start_servers = 50
#pm.min_spare_servers = 20
#pm.max_spare_servers = 70
#pm.max_requests = 10000
```

I have tried `pm ondemand` & `pm dynamic` both

Comment: Seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125831/php-fpm-reload-unable-to-read-what-child-say/41076156

Comment: @ffeast I'm using PHP 7.0.19